# Testing OpenGL ES performance

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have gotten to the stage in my project where i need to test the performance of my OpenGL ES rendering. I understand that the `OpenGL ES Performance Detective` is handy for such tasks. Unfortunately i cannot initialize a case in the application.

[image]

Does this have anything to do with my application being faulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using configuration that doesn't strip debug symbols, as this seems to help in most cases when you have any problems using instruments.

Go to edit scheme window -> select Profile App -> change build configuration to Debug.